# How to get current system year in Prolog as a number

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

How to get current system year as a number in prolog.
I found this.
But it gives the year as a string.

```
today(Today) :- get_time(X), format_time(atom(Today), '%Y', X).
```

Thanks.

Comment: yep. That is what I meant.

Comment: Use `atom_number(Today, Year)` to convert `Today` to an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I hv no idea how to do it. Could you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I think I just told you how to do it. ;) Spelling it out completely: `today(Year) :- get_time(X), format_time(atom(Today), '%Y', X), atom_number(Today, Year).` You just have to think about it a bit. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mbratch notes in the comments to my answer, `format_time/3` is for displaying date and time values. If I just needed the data, I wouldn't use `format_time/3`, but rather `stamp_date_time/3` and `date_time_value/3` to convert the time stamp into the values you need. Documentation on the relevant predicates can be found [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=timedate).

To get the current year, a predicate like this will suffice:

```
year(Year) :-
    get_time(Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, local),
    date_time_value(year, DateTime, Year).
```

Here is a descriptions of the built-in predicates used:

- `get_time/2` gives a float representing the elapsed time since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
- `stamp_date_time/3` converts the stamp to a term `date/9`, according to the time-zone indicated by the third argument. When the time-zone argument is `local` it gets the time-zone which your system takes to be local. An example of `date/9`:

  date(2014, 3, 29, 8, 8, 59.30211305618286, 21600, 'MDT', true)
- `date_time_value/3`: lets you extract values from a `date/9` term (so you don't have to do silly things like `date(Year,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_)` to get a simple value).

Your question asks for the year, but your example predicate looks like it describes today's date, which would look like this:

```
today(Today) :-
    get_time(Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, local),
    date_time_value(date, DateTime, Today).
```

The with the `date` keyword, `date_time_value/3` will instantiate `Today` to a term `date/3`, holding the year, month, and day: e.g., `date(2014, 3, 29)`.

Really, it's a bit silly that the library requires three statements to get a common date-time value, so if you're handling time and dates often, you might just want to use a general purpose predicate like

```
get_date_time_value(Key, Value) :-
    get_time(Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, local),
    date_time_value(Key, DateTime, Value).
```

Which will return the current numerical value corresponding to the given `Key`:

```
?- get_date_time_value(day, X).
X = 29.

?- get_date_time_value(year, X).
X = 2014.

?- get_date_time_value(date, X).
X = date(2014, 3, 29).
```

Comment: Yes (+1), this makes more sense than using a date format predicate (designed for displaying date strings) to extract part of a date.